# Unexpected material change

Tags: materials

Applying Materials, I selected one face, selected a new material and clicked Assign but the material was added to everything but the face I selected, why?

Comment: Does this happen often? It might be possible to find out if you share the file.

Comment: Thank you Jackdaw, It happens every time. I don't know how to share the file as this program can't see the blender file, do I need to "export" to create the type file I can share? Obviously I'm new at this.

Comment: Here is a link to the answer to the upload question. Read the instructions in blendexchange page carefully since it's not that intuitive. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file